# any web3 event callback to notify the account balance change

Tags: web3js

The app below is to send the eth value to the account and refresh the account balance. however the balance doesn't show immediately.

```
   // send the eth to the contract 
   contract.methods.create(model)
                     .send({from: account,value:value })
                     .on('transactionHash', function(hash){
                               console.log('hash',hash);
                      })

   // refresh the account to see the balance
    web3.eth.getBalance(address, function (error, result) {
      if (error) {
      } else {

        }
    })
```

I am just wondering is there a event callback on web3 to notify the account balance change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using web3 v1? In v1 you can use `.then()` from the result of send to chain getBalance after the transaction was mined.

```
// send the eth to the contract 
contract.methods.create(model)
    .send({from: account,value:value })
    .on('transactionHash', function(hash){
        console.log('hash',hash);
    })
    .then(function () {
        // refresh the account to see the balance
        web3.eth.getBalance(address, function (error, result) {
            if (error) {
            } else {
            }
        })
    })
```

There's no event for balance changes that I'm aware of, but installing a block filter and checking for balance chanes should work.